# How to properly select checkbox on load in a jQuery DataTables using .select() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm implementing the jQuery DataTables checkbox, and want to populate the checkbox with a checkbox on load. What is other function or extension can use to tick or check a checkbox on a jQuery DataTables?

```js
var $currentRow = [1, 2, 3, 4];

taskDataTableUser.rows().every(function(rowIndex) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $currentRow.length; i++) {

    console.log($currentRow[rowIndex]);

    if ($currentRow[rowIndex]) {
      taskDataTableUser.row(rowIndex).data().select(); // Not Working
    }

  }
});
```

I expect the output to check a checkbox on a respected row in DataTables.

Example:

row 1 check the checkbox
row 2 check the checkbox
row 3 check the checkbox
row 4 check the checkbox

Comment: looking [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/integration), try `taskDataTableUser.row(rowIndex).select();`

Comment: @BenG thanks for help, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Any errors? Its sets the tick on the order of items and **not** the _Order_ on the table. double check all pages that none are checked.

Comment: can you have a configuration or example? I think I have wrong configuration on the DataTable options.